# Get error code 400 when send request on stripe for get token

Tags: angular, angular6, stripe-payments

This is My Object for get bank account token

```
this.myObject= {
    country: 'US',
    currency: 'usd',
    routing_number: '110000000',
    account_number: '000123456789',
    account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    account_holder_type: 'individual',
 };
```

This is my function to get the token from stripe...
How can i get bank account token from stripe

```
getTokenOFBankAccount(myObject: any): Observable<any> {
  this.spinner.show();
  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({Authorization: "Bearer "+ 
 environment.stripeToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
  }
  return this.http
    .post<any>("https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens", myObject, headers)
    .pipe(
      tap(response => {
        debugger;
        this.spinner.hide();
        if (response["status"] === "successful") {


        } else {

        }
      })
    );
 }
```

How can i get Bank account token from Stripe. what is the best way to get 
   Bank account token from Stripe.  How can i get Bank account token from 
   Stripe. what is the best way to get 
   Bank account token from Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send signed request directly from client. If you need to creat Stripe token on client use Stripe.JS library, it uses publishable key. Never expose your Stripe secret key.

Comment: Evgenii Malikov thanks for your response! can you please tell me how can i used stripe.js  in angular6?? i can't find any way??

Comment: it's possible to write your own wrapper around Stripe.js, but I suggest you to
take a look into this or similar libraries
https://github.com/AckerApple/stripe-angular